# How to create android library having activity and other third party dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library, aar

I have created android library before without Activity or resource in it. But now I want to create library with Activity and other third party dependencies. I couldn't find any complete article for this. Any idea or any link which I can refer would be a great help.

Comment: Do you have any problem on it? With android library you can add any activity and resource: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#Convert

Comment: @JohnLe I have an Application class in my library now when I tried to use this library there is an error which says context is null, so can I have Application class in library if yes the how can I pass context to my library?

Comment: I have never tried it before. You should post the detail error so the others can help you